# I cannot append my python data to JSON file properly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I cannot append my python data to JSON in a correct way, I have tried soo many solutions but nothing has worked to get me the final result. I want to make a sign up form using python when the data is entered it is entered in the json file like this

```
{
"User_Data":[
    "user_no_1":{
       "First_name":first_name
       "second_name":second_name
       "last_name":last_name
        },

    "user_no_2":{
       "First_name":first_name
       "second_name":second_name
       "last_name":last_name
       },

    "user_no_3":{
       "First_name":first_name
       "second_name":second_name
       "last_name":last_name
       }

   ]

}
```

But when i run this python code:

```
import json

jsonFile_read_user_data = open("test.json", "r")
    
    
data = json.load(jsonFile_read_user_data)

first_name = input('Please enter your first name:')
second_name = input('Please enter your second name:')
last_name = input('Please enter your first name:')

data_inputed = {"user_no_1": {"first_name": first_name, "second_name": second_name, "last_name": last_name}}

data["USER_DATA"].append(data_inputed)

jsonFile_write_user_data = open("test.json", "w")

str = json.dump(data, jsonFile_write_user_data, indent = 4)

jsonFile_write_user_data.seek(0)
```

This is what my data appear on the test.json:

```
{
    "USER_DATA": [
        {
            "user_no_1": {
                "first_name": "yassin",
                "second_name": "ahmed",
                "last_name": "rakha"
            }
        },
        {
            "user_no_2": {
                "first_name": "jhon",
                "second_name": "doe",
                "last_name": "escobar"
            }
        },
        {
            "user_no_3": {
                "first_name": "elon",
                "second_name": "musk",
                "last_name": "rakha"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

All I want is to have the first example show as it is but in my test.json file, i dont know if it is a problem in my python code while trying to append or a problem in the json file.

Comment: What isn't working? You haven't actually explained.

Comment: What i want is to have my json file to be like the first example, i added what my json files look like in the last code example

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of typos/mistakes in the code you supplied that are likely causing issues:

1. The original format is *not* a JSON string - it really doesn't make sense at all. Your file is trying to represent an object of something like type `Dict[str, List[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]]]`, which cannot exist (and some commas are missing). I would suggest dropping the redundant outer key "User_Data" (since it is a singleton key, it has no purpose) instead create an object of type `Dict[str, Dict[str, str]]` and add commas and make everything lowercase to standardize it, like this:

`{"user_no_1": { "first_name":"James", "middle_name": "Herbert", "last_name":"Bond"}, ...}`

2. Simplify your code and make it match this new datatype (note that `dict` has no `append` method).

Using `with` and some dictionary comprehensions, we get:

```
with open("test.json", 'r+') as user_data_file:
    data = json.load(user_data_file)
    names = {f'{x}_name': input(f'Please enter your {x} name: ') for x in ['first', 'second', 'last']}
    data.update({'user_no_1': names}) # The |= is more concise, but only available with Python 3.9
    json.dump(data, user_data_file, indent=4)
    user_data_file.seek(0) # not really necessary, but I'll leave it in
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much for the help with this thing i really appreciate it, but i just wanted to like create a sign up, login system using python and json only, so are there any suggestions on makeing this possible

Comment: I wantred to do this thing so i can get the email and password when someone tries to log in, so do you think i can do it, like my ideia was to get the data like this "user_no"["first name"]. But i will do the same for email and password, i hope you help me with this, and if you dont quite understand i will try to tell it in a more simplified way

Comment: I mean, log into what? If you mean on a website, you will need some way to interface with the site (if so, check out the `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` libraries). If you just mean more of a pretend "log-in" as in using your code, then certainly, what you have now basically does it. Just get the user's input for their email and password

Comment: As an aside, it seems painfully un-secure to store someone's password as raw text in a simple JSON dictionary - that is practically begging for someone to hack you.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your help with my problem